# How can i resolve face spoofing to stop unauthorized access in face recognition system using android?

Tags: android, kotlin, face-detection, android-camera2, google-vision

I am working on a face recognition based attendance system. I am using com.google.mlkit:face-detection library for face detection by camera image analysis. I am facing a problem with face spoofing i.e. if someone shows his/her face using a phone or photo that also get detected. Is there any pre-trained library to resolve this issue? or is there any other way i can use in the android app such that i can check the depth of the person on camera before hitting the API. ?

I am working on a face recognition based attendance system. I am using com.google.mlkit:face-detection library for face detection by camera image analysis. I am facing a problem with face spoofing i.e. if someone shows his/her face using a phone or photo that also get detected. Is there any pre-trained library to resolve this issue? or is there any other way i can use in the android app such that i can check the depth of the person on camera before hitting the API. ?

I am new for this technology. So i need help to resolve this problem.

Comment: I too faced this issue, with com.google.mlkit:face-detection, so I switched to Mitek system's Facial recognition SDK, which was a module in their Bundled SDK, it was different from google's but it worked for me! even you can try.

Comment: The security of a face recognition system is to my knowledge mostly determined by the camera. Without a depth sensor you can only try to implement a "liveness detection" e.g. if eys move or something like that.